# how to make iPhone screen stay on during video call

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am providing video call feature in my application, but how can i make the screen stay on, during video call, normally the screen sleeps after a min or two and the video session stream is being destroyed, how to make the screen stay on during the video session even the user don't tap or touch anything on the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop your app from timing out and going to sleep you can use:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

This will obviously, disable the idle timer and stop your iPhone from automatically going into sleep mode.

You should re-enable the idle timer when you no longer need to keep the phone awake (generally after that view has been removed) using:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = NO;
```